# Working with time-series data that is in LST timezone, WITHOUT daylight savings time. How can I convert this to PST8PDT?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am working in Pandas with NOAA hourly meteorological data, which is recorded in Local Standard Time (without regard for daylight savings time). How can I convert this to LST with Daylight Savings?

So far I have tried adding an 8 hour offset to the tz naive datetime data, localizing to UTC, then converting back to PST8PDT, but that did not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
Date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE) + pd.Timedelta('8 hours')
Date_time = Date_time.dt.tz_localize('UTC')
Date_time = Date_time.dt.tz_convert('PST8PDT')
```

EDIT: Thank you for all the help! I localized with the fixed offset (UTC-8), but when I convert to 'America/Los_Angeles' or 'PST8PDT' it seems like all the datetimes are off by -8 or -7 hours, unless I am misunderstanding the datetime conventions.

To illustrate the problem:
Here's the raw time data [image: Raw NOAA time data]

Here's the datetime data after I localize to UTC with fixed offset [image]

And here's the datetime data after I convert to "America/Los_Angeles" time zone. [image]

As you can see, it applies Daylight Savings Time, however I am confused by the fact that all the datetimes say "-08:00" or "-07:00". Does that mean that 8 or 7 hours is being subtracted from each displayed datetime? Or am I misinterpreting that?

Either way, the good news is I found that if I just leave the data in UTC timezone with the fixed offset, I am able to work with it without any issues.

Comment: Hi. The term "LST" stands for [Local Sidereal Time](https://greenbankobservatory.org/education/great-resources/lst-clock/), and is not commonly used. (I doubt your data is in [sidereal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time).) You said it was "local standard time" - If you mean local time as if it were standard time year-round, that is *possible*, but would also seem unlikely, because that would place an hour a day during the entire DST period into the wrong date. It would help if you edit your question to include some examples, and also linked to the source of the data set. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I meant Local Standard Time (PST in this case). The data is from NOAA's Climate Data Online database. https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/ From their website: "Time: Time of observation given as a 4-digit number using a 24-hour clock in local standard time (e.g. 1751 =
5:51 pm LST). No adjustments are made to account for Daylight Savings Time (DST)."

Comment: Ok, I found the data set [here](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/metadata/geoportal/rest/metadata/item/gov.noaa.ncdc:C00684/html), and you're right.  It's using standard time all year round.  To correct, you should first localize with a fixed offset (such as UTC-8), then convert to the full IANA time zone (such as `America/Los_Angeles`).  You should be able to do this with either pytz or dateutil (I don't think pandas yet supports zoneinfo).  I can add an example tomorrow, if someone else doesn't beat me to it. :)

Comment: basically just replace `'PST8PDT'` with `'America/Los_Angeles'` in your code and you're all set. I wonder why NOAA creates such confusion in the first place...

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint based on what I observed during usage, pandas datetime *does accept* ZoneInfo tz objects. But I'd recommend to use the built-in methods anyway (`tz_localize` etc.) so that internally, the package can do whatever is best-suited (I think it's still based on pytz).

Comment: @FObersteiner - Ok.  I was just seeing that [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37654) was still open.  I hadn't read the detail.  Also, isn't there a better way to assign the fixed offset than to shift and localize as UTC?  I suppose that gets the same effect, but it certainly is error prone.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint thanks for the link; not knowing all the details I was assuming this would go pretty deep. The issue #37654 also shows some examples [#1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37654#issuecomment-723505047), [#2](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37654#issuecomment-939377451) why I made the suggestion above - all fine if using the built-ins.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I found that if I just localize it to UTC with the fixed offset, I am able to work with the data without any issues. I'm still not sure if it converts properly to PST/PDT (see edits to my question), however it's a non-issue if I just leave it in UTC with the offset